# Partial differentiation of $-(z-x)^4$

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Take the derivative of $$-(z-x)^4$$ with respect to $z$

This is my method using the chain rule

$$-4(z-x)^3$$

But the right answer is

$$-4(x-z)^3$$
where $x$ and $z$ have switched signs.

Why so? What happened to make the variables switch sign?

Thanks

Comment: Your's is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing happened, you are right when you say the answer is

$$-4(z-x)^3.$$

The chain rule works perfectly here.

If a book gives a different answer, it is probably a typo.

**Edit**

Notice that

$$-4(z-x)^3=4(-1)^3(z-x)^3=4(-(z-x))^2=4(x-z)^3.$$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gave me the answers with this input $$differentiate -(z-x)^4$$

Actually, Wolfram Alpha gives $$4(x-z)^3$$ without the minus sign...

Comment: The answer of WA is $4(x-z)^3$ tha is the same as $-4(z-x)^3$

Answer (score 1):

the derivative is given by $$-4(z-x)^3$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The key fact here is that $3$ is an odd exponent, so $-(z-x)^3=(x-z)^3$.